# Creating a Tripole in Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

Good Day, I want to create a Tripole that basically shows the signal from a signal generator.
something similar like in the image below, there is a square called "PWM" that shows a square signal, how would I do such a thing in circuitikz?
[image: like this]

Comment: You have several options --- there is no such a symbol, but it is easy enough to create it in Ti*k*Z.

Comment: @Rmano can you show me a short example, maybe I can follow from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sources are basically round in `circuitikz`, so the "standard" solution would be something like:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \node[nfet, rotate=90](N){};
    \draw (N.G) -- ++(0,-1) to[sqV, l=PWM] ++(0,-1) node[ground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the square thing, you can draw it with plain Ti*k*Z command (remember, a `circuitikz` is just a `tikzpicture`):

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \node[nfet, rotate=90](N){};
    \node[draw, thick, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm](B) at ([yshift=-2cm]N.G) {};
    \draw (B.north) -- (N.G);
    \node [below] at (B.north) {PWM};
    \draw (B.south west) ++(0.1,0.1) -| ++(0.2,0.4) -| ++(0.2,-0.4) -| ++(0.2,0.4) -| ++(0.2,-0.4);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]